# Adding sourceDir to java sourceSet

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

As per the Gradle Kotlin plugin [page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-the-jvm).

> Kotlin sources can be mixed with Java sources in the same folder, or in different folders. The default convention is using different folders. The corresponding sourceSets property should be updated if not using the default convention.

I want to add some Java files in src/main/kotlin and have the compileJava task compile them. I tried to come up with the following block to achive it, but no dice.

```
java {
    val kotlinSrcDir: File = File(projectDir, "src/main/kotlin")
    sourceSets["main"].java.srcDirs.add(kotlinSrcDir)
    val javasrcdirs: Set<File> = sourceSets["main"].java.srcDirs
    println(javasrcdirs)
}
```

What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TLDR

```
java {
    val kotlinSrcDir = "src/main/kotlin"
    val mainJavaSourceSet: SourceDirectorySet = sourceSets.getByName("main").java
    mainJavaSourceSet.srcDir(kotlinSrcDir)
    println(mainJavaSourceSet.srcDirs)
}
```

### Details

When you call `srcDirs` in your `build.gradle.kts`, the actual method called is [`SourceDirectorySet.getSrcDirs()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html#getSrcDirs--). The implementation of this method in [`DefaultSourceDirectorySet.getSrcDirs()`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/file/DefaultSourceDirectorySet.java#L84) returns a defensive copy of the collection, and this is why modifying it has no effect.

So to actually add a new source directory to the set use [`srcDir(Object)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html#srcDir-java.lang.Object-) or [`srcDirs(Object...)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html#srcDirs-java.lang.Object...-).

Comment: Thanks. The eclipse kotlin editor and plugin are not complete and they are buggy. They do not provide code completion hints. I have stopped using eclipse and now switched to IntelliJ Idea, which does let me see the internals of Gradle-Kotlin-DSL implementation API so I can discover the API calls available to me. The lack of proper documentation has been frustrating, but now hopefully that will not be a big limitation.

Comment: No problem :) I started learning Gradle and Kotlin just recently, and for me trying to answer SO questions is a way to learn.

Comment: Earlier I had thought about learning Groovy, since I was unknowingly using it to program the Gradle DSL. But now since Gradle is supporting Kotlin to program the DSL. I am seriously considering abandoning Groovy and instead learn Kotlin. I will start by digging into Kotlin's reference manual.